# Vagrant Multibox - my network adapter is not being recognised

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have a problem where I am trying to assign a public_network interface for my Vagrantfile I have the right adapter selected, yet every time I run `vagrant up` it asks me to select the adapter.

The adapter I have set in the file is in the list

`web.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en4: Display Ethernet"`

I am not sure why it is asking me to choose an adapter when I have set it like this.

This is my Vagrantfile and an image of the terminal output is below that:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

config.vm.define "web01" do |web|
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3"
    web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8093
    web.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en4: Display Ethernet"
    web.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.2.230"
    #web.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"    

    web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.name = "16.04-web01"
        vb.memory = "512"
    end
end

config.vm.define :sql01 do |sql|
    sql.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2"
    sql.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8094
    sql.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en4: Display Ethernet"
    sql.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.2.231"
    #sql.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
    sql.vm.provision :shell, path: "installsql.sh"    

    sql.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.name = "16.04-sqlserver"
        vb.memory = "4096"
    end
end

#Options for Me specific
#config.vm.synced_folder "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/", "/htdocs_home"

end
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - I have tried all my adapters and I copy /pasted the values, so I would not make any mistakes.

Comment: Just tried it and no it didn't - the order seems set

Comment: That worked! A bit confused, since I had the ip specified, but oh well. If you care to put an explanation with the comment above as an answer, I will mark it as accepted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the [`config.vm.network` method](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb) twice with the same type `:public_network` but with different arguments. The second call seems to overwrite the settings performed by the first, even though the code suggests the settings should be merged.

Replace:

```
web.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en4: Display Ethernet"
web.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.2.230"
```

With a single line:

```
web.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.2.230",  bridge: "en4: Display Ethernet"
```

Comment: I presume that is so that the IP address does not overwrite the bridge?

Comment: I don't know. A brief look at the code suggests the settings settings be merged.